# how to set payment info.phtml for adminhtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

how to set payment info.phtml for adminhtml ...

like set for the frontend...something like this

```
class Ks_Gippayment_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{


protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('ks/info.phtml');
}
```

thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will also do the job for adminhtml. Just make sure the following template exists:

```
app/design/adminhtml/base/default/template/ks/info.phtml
```